# how to extract session ID from JSESSIONID at client side?

Tags: java, session, cookies, websphere

Below is an instance of JSESSIONID stored in cookie. This JSESSIONID was generated by Websphere.

0000SHOQmBQ8EokAQtzl_HYdxIt:vuel491u

I know from [this article](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248056.pdf) page 1011 that the JESSSION id consists of the following 4 part:
Cache ID,
Session ID ,
separator(the [:]),
and Clone ID / Partition ID

My question 1 is: how to extract the Session ID part?

Knowing the separator is always [:], I can get the first 2 parts.
What I am not sure is:
Does Cache ID always exist and is it always 4 digit?
Is the length of session id always the same = 23 digits?

Is there any client side API to get session ID from JSESSIONID in cookie?

Question 2:
In most of my client environment, the CacheID is always 0000, but in some other client environment, the CacheID is always 0001.
I want to know, what made this difference?

Information I gathered since this post:

> The WebSphere property HttpSessionIdLength defines length of Session
> ID and the default is 23. But Client side logic can not get this value
> and can not assume it is always 23. Since I am still not sure Cache Id is 4 digit, I am still searching for a solution..

Comment: Any reasons for getting sessionID on the client side?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149954/3701228 Client API depends on you implementation. In general if you'll take JSESSIONID cookie, the first 4 didigs are cache/epoch ID, then you have session ID till ":" and then cloneid/partitionID. So just take chars from 4 till ":".